# Systematic Way to find System of Parameters of Local Rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, noetherian, local-rings

In Noetherian local rings $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ one can always find a *system of parameters* $a_1, \dots, a_n \in \mathfrak{m}$, i.e. elements such that 
$$ \dim(R) = \min \left\{n \in \mathbb{N} : \exists a_1, \dots, a_n \in \mathfrak{m}: \mathfrak{m} = \sqrt{(a_1,\dots,a_n)} \right \}.$$
We had an exercise, where we were supposed to find a system of parameters.

As an example, let $X = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : xy = 0 \}$. Then, we were supposed to find such a system for $\mathbb{C}[X]_{(0,0)}$.

It turns out that it's not too difficult to guess a solution ($x+y$ does the job). However, is there a more systematic way?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}[X]_{(0,0)}$; it‘s the coordinate ring of an affine variety.

Comment: There is in general only one way which works in all cases. First, find all minimal prime ideals of $R$, that there are only finitely many is a theorem. If $\dim R=0$, there is nothing to do and so assume $\dim R>0$. Then, the union of minimal primes is not the maximal ideal, so pick an element $x$ in the maximal ideal, not in any minimal prime. Go modulo $x$ to get $S=R/x$. Then $\dim S=\dim R-1$ and proceed by induction.

Comment: @Mohan Thank you for your answer! I‘m not sure about one step, though. Does it really follow that $\dim(S) = \dim(R) -1$ in all cases? Can‘t it be possible that $\dim(S) = \dim(R)$? What I‘m a bit confused of in your argument is that the radical is never mentioned. (Also, just to check: Is there an easier argument to see that the union of minimal primes is not maximal than by Prime Avoidance Lemma?)

Comment: $\dim S<\dim R$ is trivial, since every maximal chain of primes in $R$ should end in a minimal prime and $x$ is not in any one of them. The equality can be proved essentially using Krull's principal ideal theorem. Radical plays no role in dimension. Prime avoidance is what I had in mind for the last question

Comment: @Mohan Okay, agreed. So why is there a radical in the statement of system of paramters, though?

Comment: A local ring $(R,M)$ is of dimension zero is equivalent to saying $\sqrt{0}=M$.

Comment: Ohh, right.. Thank you.